# Need to uninstall unrelated application before installation Installshield 2010

Tags: package, upgrade, installshield, uninstallation

apologies in advance, I am still an Installshield newbie!

I am currently using installsheild 2010 for an isntall packed for my application (ds2). My trouble is I need to remove a previous incarnation of that project which was created with an installshield 2008 as a merge module (ds1), not a installer in its own right.

So the old version  (ds1) is currently lacking in upgrade code etc, and only has access to a Product Version and Package code.

The new program has the usuall Upgrade, package, product codes (ds2).

Is there anyway to either associate the old product mergeModule to the new application so it can be uninstalled as a 'previous version'. Or is there another method where i can ask installshield to "remove anything with product code xxxxxxxx"

I hope that's clear enough for a response!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the msi files of the old application versions, at least?

Comment: yes, but the original product was attached to multiple installers - and I don't want to uninstall everything to do with the previous installation, just the associated product merge module (I'm sorry, this isn't very clear at all!)

Comment: I plan to write up different answers for you. So please do check on a regular basis often. One thing you should start thinking is...You need to hack or troubleshoot what the installer has done.

Answer (score 1):

UpgradeCode is only needed for FindRelatedProducts to determine the ProductCode.   RemoveExistingProducts uses that ProductCode to do the removal.

You can author a Major Upgrde based on a fake UpgradeCode knowing that it won't find anything.  Then you can use a Type 51 Set Property custom action to assign the known ProductCode to the ActionProperty used by the Major Upgrade rule.   Then RemoveExistingProducts will come by and uninstall that product.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't appear to be uninstalling the old product. I think it is because i have a "package code" not a 'product code' from the old installshield ism - which i had hoped would evaluate to the same thing. I think this is the correct way to go about this, i just need to make the 2008 mergemodule have something in common with the 2010 package :(

Comment: No, I would pray that the PackageCode and ProductCode property guids ( or any guids for that matter ) are never the same.  The fact that you are using merge modules has nothing to do with the problem at hand because merge modules are not products and have neither a PackageCode or a ProductCode.

Comment: of course! I do not want them to be the same. I think my point was lost. As stated, the old product existed as a mergemodule for a another project. Since the new product has an installer of its own, I can't go by the usual upgrade codes to get the old product uninstalled.